# css - have two inline inputs take up remaining space

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div id="holder">
    <span>Search for</span>
    <input id="srchfor" />
    <span>near</span>
    <input id="srchin" />
    <span>submit</span>
</div>
```

The containing div is fixed width. The width of the 3 spans will depend on font size. Is it possible to make the two inputs take a width so that they are both equally sized, and they consume all the remaining space in `holder`? Or does this require using javascript?

Edit: My aim is to have the 5 elements all on one line, rather than split over several lines.

Comment: Yeah you need javascript.  Or you can use table.  Table is pretty nice for layout, table is not evil - we just didn't have choice before css.

Comment: I suspected I might have to use a table, but I didn't really want to.

Comment: Well, if supported browser list is up to date, I imagine a css two-column layout would work. You can do it with CSS, I remeber now, but it's pretty complicated.  Things like creating virtual boxes with relative position and size and put the input in them.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post but I came across it and figured I would answer it for the next person.  Here is a CSS/HTML snippet that should resolve this issue.  It is kind of like a HTML5 flexbox but without HTML5 or a flexbox.  You can add width to whatever 2 sections needed and the third will fill the remaining void.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .form-group {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 75%;
    }

    .a {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: 30%;
    }

    .a input {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .b {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 33%;
    }

    .b input {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .c {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .c input {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="a">
            <label>Thing 1</label><br />
            <input type="text" />
        </span>

        <span class="b">
            <label>Thing 2</label><br />
            <input type="text" />
        </span>

        <span class="c">
            <label>Thing 3</label><br>
            <input type="text" />
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="a">
            <label>Thing 1</label><br />
            <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div class="b">
            <label>Thing 2</label><br />
            <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div class="c">
            <label>Thing 3</label><br>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could change the display type from `display: inline` to `display: block` to make them fill space. But I don't know if the inline is an requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a fixed width for the span elements, and use the display:inline-block property like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JoseFaeti/ewZz2/12/).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that doesn't do what I need - my aim was for the 5 elements to be all on one line.